# GNOME-Terminal: Create new terminal tab on remote machine

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

Is there a way to open a new terminal tab in GNOME-Terminal when working on a remote machine that is connected via ssh?

Comment: Other than using tmux or screen?

Comment: That's on your local machine. You can either open a new tab and SSH to the remote box, or run tmux or screen on the remote box...

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/94930/gnome-terminal-new-tab-dbus

Comment: I think what I was looking for something like tmux. Thanks for your answers. you saved a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tmux (or screen, the older alternative) are great for this.

tmux lets you do both horizontal and vertical splits.

You'll probably want to customize tmux, e.g. most people like cmd-a over cmd-b as the 'prefix' key.

I use the following ~/.tmuf.conf file settings to make it work better for me:

```
# mdd tmux settings
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"  # Reload with ctrl-r
set -g prefix C-a         # prefix from ctrl-b to ctrl-a
unbind C-b                # allow ctrl-b for other things
set -sg escape-time 1     # quicker responses
bind C-a send-prefix      # Pass on ctrl-a for other apps
set -g base-index 1        # Numbering of windows
setw -g pane-base-index 1  # Numbering of Panes
# bind | split-window -h    # Split panes horizontal
bind \ split-window -h    # Split panes horizontal
bind - split-window -v    # Split panes vertically
bind h select-pane -L     # Switch to Pane Left
bind j select-pane -D     # Switch to Pane Down
bind k select-pane -U     # Switch to Pane Up
bind l select-pane -R     # Switch to Pane Right
bind -r C-h select-window -t :-  # Quick Pane Selection
bind -r C-l select-window -t :+  # Quick Pane Selection
bind -r H resize-pane -L 5       # Switch to Pane Left
bind -r J resize-pane -D 5       # Switch to Pane Down
bind -r K resize-pane -U 5       # Switch to Pane Up
bind -r L resize-pane -R 5       # Switch to Pane Right
setw -g mode-mouse off           # Mouse Off
set -g mouse-select-pane off     # Mouse Off  
set -g mouse-resize-pane off     # Mouse Off
set -g mouse-select-window off   # Mouse Off
#set -g  default-terminal "screen-256color"
setw -g monitor-activity on      # Activity Alerts
set -g visual-activity on
set -g status-fg white           # Status line Colors
set -g status-bg black
setw -g window-status-fg cyan    # Window list color
setw -g window-status-bg default
setw -g window-status-attr dim
setw -g window-status-current-fg white     # Active Window Color
setw -g window-status-current-bg red
setw -g window-status-current-attr bright
set -g pane-border-fg green      # Pane colors
set -g pane-border-bg black 
set -g pane-active-border-fg white 
set -g pane-active-border-bg yellow
set -g message-fg white          # Command/Message Line.
set -g message-bg black
set -g message-attr bright
set -g status-left-length 40     # Status Line, left side
set -g status-left "#[fg=white]Session: #S #[fg=yellow]#I #[fg=cyan]#P"
set -g status-utf8 on            # Status Line, right side
set -g status-right "-------"
set -g status-interval 60        # frequency of status line updates
set -g status-justify centre     # center window list
setw -g mode-keys vi             # vi keys to move 
unbind v                         # Open panes in same directory as tmux-panes script
unbind n
bind v send-keys " ~/tmux-panes -h" C-m
bind n send-keys " ~/tmux-panes -v" C-m
unbind Up                        # Maximizing and Minimizing...
bind Up new-window -d -n tmp \; swap-pane -s tmp.1 \; select-window -t tmp
unbind Down
bind Down last-window \; swap-pane -s tmp.1 \; kill-window -t tmp
bind P pipe-pane -o "cat >>~/#W.log" \; display "Toggled logging to ~/#W.log"
# Make keys for copy mode be like vi
unbind [
bind Escape copy-mode
unbind p
bind p paste-buffer
bind -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

I also set the following aliases (in my ~/.bash_aliases file) to let me switch between scrolling and being able to copy text:

```
alias tof='tmux set -g mode-mouse off'
alias ton='tmux set -g mode-mouse on'
```