# New terminator window on remote server

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnome-terminator

Is there a way to open a new terminator pane on a remote server when connected by ssh?

I am looking for something similar to what can be done (according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44023/22222)) by tmux but using terminator instead. I want to ssh to a remote machine using terminator, and then if I split the terminator window, the new shell will open on the remote machine.

Comment: I don't think this possible as every split spawns a new local shell, so having it spawn a remote shell you'd need to make a new session with that split on the remote server. This would be quite different to how screen and tmux works.

Comment: @Bobby, yeah I figured as much but maybe some superuser out there has a hack ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this problem for terminator and remote systems is to create a terminator profile, where the command it runs 'as a login shell' is the SSH connection string used to access the remote server. It is prefered to have SSH key based authentication or openssh controlmaster/controlpath setup to have connection sharing.

Exerpt of a terminator config for this:

`~/.config/terminator/config`

```
[profiles]
[[default]]
 scroll_on_output = False
 exit_action = restart
 scrollback_infinite = True
[[remotehost]]
 use_custom_command = True
 exit_action = restart
 custom_command = ssh user@remotehost
```

And simply run `terminator -p remotehost` to use this profile. Each time you 'split' terminals, it uses this profile and thus opens a new SSH connection.

For ssh controlmaster, see: 
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/290

Comment: Almost perfect, thanks! Extra brownie points for suggesting a way this can be done from an already launched terminator (automatically). I am accepting your answer anyway because it is a great solution.

Comment: Terrific. Don't forget run `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` before `terminator` for `SSH key based` authentication method

Answer (score 2):

ClonedSplittingMenu Terminator plugin (https://github.com/ilgarm/terminator_plugins)  is what you are looking for. It adds Clone horizontally, Clone vertically menu items and allows reopening of ssh session by splitting the window. Installation is straightforward

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/terminator/plugins
cd ~/.config/terminator/plugins
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/ilgarm/terminator_plugins/raw/master/clone_session.py
# Restart Terminator, go to plugin menu and activate ClonedSplittingMenu plugin
```

Also checkout a blog post about the plugin http://lazylabs.org/blog/terminator-plugin-to-clone-current-ssh-session/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore with terminator v.1.91